# Odd behavior with SSRS 2016 drop down parameter list

Tags: ssrs, parameter

I have a report that is "working" fine except for an issue.

I have four dropdown list parameters where I am getting the values from queries. When I select a value from a dropdown list, it selects the next value below what I wanted to select, and "removes" the first value as an option. For instance, one of the dropdowns holds a list of payrolls. When getting the list from a query, it returns payrolls 1 through 121(or so), which is perfect. However, if I try to select any of the payrolls, say payroll 10, it will show me that I selected payroll 11, and the option to select payroll 1 will no longer be available.

ALSO, possibly tied to the above, the report sometimes refreshes when I select "view report" and I have to try to choose the payroll again.

These are not cascading parameters. The values are all derived from two queries where I am selecting a distinct list of employees for two of the parameters and a distinct list of payrolls for the other two.

I am at a loss as to why this type of behavior is even possible.

Comment: the SSRS team is aware of the issue and is looking at a fix.

Comment: The problem goes away in Windows 10 Version 1709

Answer (score 3):

After desperately trying everything from restarting and updating SSRS, to clicking my heels three times and throwing salt over my shoulder, **the solution is to not use the Microsoft Edge browser.** When I switch to using Chrome/Firefox to run my SSRS reports, the behavior is removed.

Microsoft Edge version: 38.14393.0.0

Comment: You may want to add a bug report item to http://connect.microsoft.com for Edge.

Comment: I've had so may issues with Microsoft Edge that I stopped using it altogether and removed it from my desktop and start bar. I switched back to Internet Explorer and Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: @hot2use *Gasp* Switched back to IE?  That is desperation my friend :)